# onRestart -> onStart() what happen between this 2 state

Tags: android

I've 2 Activity A & B.. A starts B when i return from B to A onRestart() is called, then onStart() method is called. 
My question is all the views in Activity A redraws when onRestart() -> onStart()?

Comment: We do not understand what you need. Could you rewrite your question more clearly ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Just `onResume(.)` is called if `Activity` A is not yet destroyed
  (variables are retained, no redraw).
- If it's destroyed `onCreate(.)` >    `onStart(.)` > `onResume(.)` is
  called(variables are lost, redraw).
- If it's stopped `onRestart(.)` > `onStart(.)` > `onResume(.)` is
  called(variables are not lost, redraw)

Thus you'll only loose variables if the `Activity` is cleared from memory.

Comment: K i got it nothing happens to variables, what about views, will they redraw

Comment: Yes they will, answer updated.

Comment: Thank u very much.. one more question i've have I toggle between these two activities continuesly for 30+ times then OutOfMemory Exception Occurs.. Is that bcoz every time Activity redraws..?

Comment: @Pradeep Sadly I cant answer that question with so little info. Will ask a new question with relevent parts of the code you're using and a stacktrace of the OOM?

Comment: K i'll updated i few mins Thanks

Comment: Please don't update this question. Ask a new one. You are prone to get more answers that way.